# Inserting Array into Bigquery using Google Adwords Script

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery / adwords Script - not sure why this isn't working. 
dataset is core_shopping , table is shopping_groups and it has one string field called shopping_group.  Yet the following code runs but makes no changes and inserts no rows.

What am I missing?

```
var arrProducts = [];
arrProducts.push( {shopping_group: "test" });
BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll({'rows': arrProducts} , "myproject", "core_shopping", "shopping_groups");
```

Comment: Check the response from `insertAll`--it probably includes an error telling you what is going wrong.

Comment: In addition, what do the logs show?

Comment: Thank you - so the logs say nothing and no changes made. If I show the results of insert errors it says.

    [{index=0, errors=[{reason=invalid, location=, debugInfo=, message=}]}]

Which isn't that helpful. I can't figure out what would be valid!